# setup odes in python

Tags: python, numpy, ode

how to setup the following odes with the corresponding initial conditions in python?

> `x'(t) =x(t) - y(t) - e^t`
>
> `y'(t) =x(t) + y(t) + 2e^t`
>
> with `x(0)= -1` and `y(0)= -1` and `0 <= t <= 4`

The following is what I have so far:

```
def f(u, t):
    x, y = u
    return [x+y-e**t, x+y+2*e**t]

x0, y0 = [-1.0,-1.0]
t = numpy.linspace( 0,4,50 )
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the problem? Please be a lot more specific.

Comment: Also, you got that `e` defined somewhere? In any case, you should use `math.exp()` for that.

Comment: You should use numpy.exp because it's a vectorized version of math.exp (at least in spirit, because numpy.exp is much more efficient ).

Comment: I don't have any experience with numpy so I'll have to take your word for it :).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to solve them with odeint. First I'm assuming you use this prelude in you script :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
```

Your equation is :

```
def equation(X, t):
    x, y = X
    return [ x+y-np.exp(t), x+y+2*np.exp(t) ]
```

and then you can solve them with

```
init = [ -1.0, -1.0 ]
t = np.linpsace(0, 4, 50)
X = odeint(equation, init, t)
```

You can extract x(t) and y(t) with

```
x = X[:, 0]
y = X[:, 1]
```

Comment: The system is already of first-order. You are solving a second order problem in your post.

Comment: Your post solves the problem `x' = vx; vx' = x+y-exp(t); ...` which is equivalent to `x'' = x+y-exp(t); ...`. Hence, you solve a second order problem by rewriting it as first-order equations. This is also apparent from the fact that your function returns a fourth-dimensional vector.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your effort.

Comment: OMG : Does it answers your question?

Comment: @deufeufeu: There is no mention of scipy in the question, so you should add `from scipy.integrate import odeint` to your answer.

Comment: @deufeufeu: Yes, thanks!! however I am using the "AdamsBashforth4" (which is defined in the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748433/python-code-for-multiple-ode/16756424#16756424))  and when I executed it, it shoes me the following error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in X = AdamsBashforth4(equation, init, t) File "", line 15, in AdamsBashforth4 f0 = f( x[:-1], t[:-1] ) File "", line 2, in equation x, y = X ValueError: too many values to unpack