# solve ode using multistep solver

Tags: python, numpy, ode

The following is the code for multiple solvers so far. 
The system for this problem is here, [our system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747624/setup-odes-in-python?noredirect=1#comment24123067_16747624) 
However, when I execute it in Python, it shows me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\math3511\assignment\assignment5\qu2", line 59, in 
X = AdamsBashforth4(equation, init, t)
File "G:\math3511\assignment\assignment5\qu2", line 32, in AdamsBashforth4
k2 = h * f( x[i] + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + 0.5 * h )
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

the code:

```
import numpy
from numpy import array, exp, linspace

def AdamsBashforth4( f, x0, t ):
    """
    Fourth-order Adams-Bashforth method::

        u[n+1] = u[n] + dt/24.*(55.*f(u[n], t[n]) - 59*f(u[n-1], t[n-1]) +
                                37*f(u[n-2], t[n-2]) - 9*f(u[n-3], t[n-3]))

    for constant time step dt.

    RK2 is used as default solver for first steps.
    """

    n = len( t )
    x = numpy.array( [ x0 ] * n )

    # Start up with 4th order Runge-Kutta (single-step method).  The extra
    # code involving f0, f1, f2, and f3 helps us get ready for the multi-step
    # method to follow in order to minimize the number of function evaluations
    # needed.

    f1 = f2 = f3 = 0
    for i in xrange( min( 3, n - 1 ) ):
        h = t[i+1] - t[i]
        f0 = f( x[i], t[i] )
        k1 = h * f0
        k2 = h * f( x[i] + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + 0.5 * h )
        k3 = h * f( x[i] + 0.5 * k2, t[i] + 0.5 * h )
        k4 = h * f( x[i] + k3, t[i+1] )
        x[i+1] = x[i] + ( k1 + 2.0 * ( k2 + k3 ) + k4 ) / 6.0
        f1, f2, f3 = ( f0, f1, f2 )



    for i in xrange( n - 1 ):
        h = t[i+1] - t[i]
        f0 = f( x[i], t[i] )
        k1 = h * f0
        k2 = h * f( x[i] + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + 0.5 * h )
        k3 = h * f( x[i] + 0.5 * k2, t[i] + 0.5 * h )
        k4 = h * f( x[i] + k3, t[i+1] )
        x[i+1] = x[i] + h * ( 9.0 * fw + 19.0 * f0 - 5.0 * f1 + f2 ) / 24.0
        f1, f2, f3 = ( f0, f1, f2 )

    return x



def equation(X, t):
    x, y = X
    return [ x+y-exp(t), x+y+2*exp(t) ]

init = [ -1.0, -1.0 ]
t = linspace(0, 4, 50)
X = AdamsBashforth4(equation, init, t)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that f is returning a sequence (list, tuple, or like) and there's no operation to multiply all items in a sequence by a value.

Dirk is right, looking at your algorithm, your equation should return (even if it small) a numpy array, as you can scalar-multiply a numpy array. So keeping your code but embedding your return in equation with an array. Like this:

```
np.array([1,2]) # a numpy array containing [1,2]
```

Comment: You should probably return a numpy array instead of a python list (in the `equation` function).

Comment: @deufeufeu
while how can I setup in Python, if I wanna 'use the analytical solution to find the starting value': the analytical solution is x(t)=e^t*cos(t)-2*e^t;y(t)=e^t*sin(t)-e^t